# How to dynamically change a collectionView Item size (like instagram) using segmented control

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, instagram, segmentedcontrol

How can I build a UICollectionView similar to the Instagram one?
I already created the three columns one:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let width = (view.frame.width/3)-2

    myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 49, left: 1, bottom: 1.5, right: 1)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1

    myCollectionView?.dataSource = self
    myCollectionView?.delegate = self
    myCollectionView?.register(PhotoGalleryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellid)
    myCollectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView!)

    myCollectionView!.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myCollectionView!.topAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    segmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myCollectionView!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    segmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    segmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myCollectionView!.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
```

But I want the Collection view's items to become a 1 column width when the selectedControl's value becomes 1, and then if the value goes back to 0 the collectionView goes back to a 3 columns setup.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `layout` of the `collectionView` based on the expected UI - *grid or list*, when switching between the `segments` of `UISegmentedControl`.

First of all, create an `enum LayoutType` like,

```
enum LayoutType {
    case list, grid
}
```

Now, in your `ViewController`, create a property `layoutType` of type `LayoutType` initially set to `.list`, i,e.

```
var layoutType = LayoutType.list
```

Next, implement the `@IBAction` for `segmentedControl's` `valueChanged` event. So, till now the `ViewController` looks like.

```
class VC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var layoutType = LayoutType.list

    @IBAction func onChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            layoutType = .list
        } else {
            layoutType = .grid
        }
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Now implement the `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods as required. You must've done that already.

Now to change the `layout` based on the `layoutType`, you need to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol and implement the below methods,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    switch layoutType {
    case .list:
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 50)
    case .grid:
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.width - 20) / 3, height: 50)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}
```

This is how you can proceed with the things. Let me know in case you still face any issue.